Numerical methods for ODEs where all variables are matrecies
I am currently trying to replicate the 'Numerical Results' section of this paper for my own interest. My current sticking point is solving the below system of ODEs where all the variables are matrecies:
\begin{equation} A'(t)=A(t)M^A A(t)+A(t)U^A+(U^A)^TA(t)+R^A\end{equation}
\begin{equation} B'(t)=A(t)M^A B(t)+A(t)V^B+(U^A)^TB(t)\end{equation}
In the above equations all variables except A(t), B(t), A'(t) and B'(t) are known. A'(t) and B'(t) are the first derivatives of A(t) and B(t) respectively and A(T) and B(T) are their values at terminal time t=T and are known.
As I know the terminal values at time T, I have tried to solve using the implicit Euler method where, where I am stepping back in time a small timestep dt until I reach t=0:
\begin{equation} A(t-1)=A(t) - (A(t)M^A A(t)+A(t)U^A+(U^A)^TA(t)+R^A) * 
 dt\end{equation}
\begin{equation} B(t-1)=B(t) - (A(t)M^A B(t)+A(t)V^B+(U^A)^TB(t)) * dt\end{equation}
However, the solutions I am producing at t=0 don't seem to match the output of the paper. So my question is this. Can I use the implicit Euler method in this manor to solve for an entire matrix or am I missing something? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
The definition of the matrices can be found in the below linked image.
Matrix definitions
Where:
\begin{equation} \alpha_{2} = 0.741 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \gamma = 3 * 10^{-4}\end{equation}
\begin{equation} n^S= 7 * 10^{-8}\end{equation}
\begin{equation} n^F= 3 * 10^{-8}\end{equation}
\begin{equation} K_E= 8\end{equation}
\begin{equation} K_D= 0\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \Sigma =  \begin{bmatrix}
    19600       & 0 & 0  \\
    0       & 25 & 0  \\
    0   &   0 & 0 &
\end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \sum_{}^{tilde} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    25 & 0  \\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
and Z has discrete values for which lambda values are also specified in the below linked image.
Z and lambda values

Low-order methods should only be used as proof-of-concept over small time intervals using small time steps. For everything else use well-tested high-order methods with step-size control. The Euler method with negative step size is not the implicit Euler method (in the dynamic of the computation).

Could you please explain $U^A$, $V^B$, $M^A$ and, if not trivial, how you compute them.

Thank you very much for your questions, I have updated my post with the matrix definitions and the variables contained within them. I would really appreciate any guidence you can offer.

So that is not some weird exponential function, but an upper index to denote some constant matrices. As $M^A$ is not positive definite, both integration directions have expanding subspaces. This usually means that the initial values have to be carefully tuned so that the solution stays finite long enough. But in numerical solutions, the admissible initial conditions also depend on the method and the step size sequence.
